# Need a subquery in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql

I want to Select all items in this table :

```
_categoryRepository.Table :

Id  Name

1   Birthday
2   Christmas
4   Desktops
6   Notebooks
7   Accessories
9   Cell phones
```

But, . . I want to exclude any 'Id' from _categoryRepository that match 'EventID' in this table :

```
_MemberEventRepository.Table

Id  MemID   EventID

1   1   1
3   1   2
5   1   7
7   4   1
8   4   4
```

that matches the MemId. So for MemID '1', the results would be :

```
4   Desktops
6   Notebooks
9   Cell phones
```

I don't know how to do this in LINQ.

```
    var eventsList = from c in _categoryRepository.Table
                    join m in _MemberEventRepository.Table on ?????????????
                    where (m.MemID == currentCustomer)         
                    orderby c.Name
                    select new MyActiveEvents { Id = c.Id, Name = c.Name };
```

This the SQL equivalent :

```sql
SELECT [Id] ,[Name]
FROM [Category] 
WHERE Id NOT IN 
(SELECT EventID FROM [Category] c INNER JOIN [MemberEvent] m ON m.[EventID] = c.Id)
```

Is this possible in LINQ?

Comment: Are you using `LINQ-to-sql` or `LINQ-to-entities`? Looks more like `LINQ-to-sql`, but in case of `LINQ-to-entites`: Are there entity relations defined, e.g. does a `Category` have a `Events` navigation property?

Comment: "does a Category have a Events navigation property?" No. Can't LINQ-to-sql or LINQ-to-entities both be used?

Comment: In theory they can be used in parallel, but I am not very familiar with `LINQ-to-sql` as I normaly only use `LINQ-to-entities`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be something like:

```
var categories = db.Categories
                   .Where(c => db.MemberEvents.Count(e => EventID == c.Id) == 0);
```

**Update** - using your LINQ-code-fragment:

```
var eventsList = from c in _categoryRepository.Table
                 where _MemberEventRepository.Table
                     .Count(m => m.EventID == c.id) == 0       
                 orderby c.Name
                 select new MyActiveEvents { Id = c.Id, Name = c.Name }
```

Instead of `Count(...) == 0` it should also be possible to use `!Any(...)`.

Comment: Pretty good chrfin. Worked perfectly. So few lines to do it. I wish I understood LINQ more. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an except would work? I'm not sure which solution will translate into the most efficient sql.

```
var eventsList = (from c in _categoryRepository.Table
                  orderby c.Name
                  select new MyActiveEvents { Id = c.Id, Name = c.Name })
                 .Except(
                from c in _categoryRepository.Table
                join m in _MemberEventRepository.Table on c.Id equals m.EventID
                where (m.MemID == currentCustomer)         
                select new MyActiveEvents { Id = c.Id, Name = c.Name });
```

Comment: "which solution will translate into the most efficient sql" . . I'm  more concerned about getting the job done at this point. Both solutions worked. I understand yours much more, but  would like to learn more LINQ because I'm sure it would makes things easier in the end. Thanks